# jstree checkmark color from green to black

Tags: jstree

I am using jstree to place my departments in a tree org configuration.   I would like to change the color of the checkmark from green to  black color and I am not seeing how to do that.  Does any one have an idea on how to change the checkmark color on jstree?

thank you for your help
Brian

Comment: Honestly I wasn't sure what to do to make this change.

Comment: I have tried to change the theme from default to default-dark but when I do that I loose all the check boxes.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I got the default-dark theme to work but that is not what I am looking for it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The green checkmark is an image which is available in the themes in the jsTree library. You could edit this image and change the color of the checkmark. The image used is available under dist > themes > default > 32px.png

Here's the github link

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/dist/themes/default/32px.png

Alternatively you could also use the dark theme available in the jsTree distribution.

```
"core": {
    "themes": { "name": "default-dark" }
},
```